# Recursive Inner Functions Golang

Tags: go, recursion, depth-first-search

### Recursive inner function declaration golang

#### Is it supposed to be ugly?

I'm currently trying to write a recurisve DFS for a leetcode problem (new to Golang)

###### Doesn't Run:

when I try to create and declare my inner function like this:

```
outerFunction (node *TreeNode, target int) bool {
  checkSolutions := func(node *TreeNode, total int) bool {
        // ... DFS algo
        checkSolutions(node.Left)
        checkSolutions(node.Right)
    }
    
  return checkSolution(root, 0)
}
```

I don't have access to the inner function during the recursive call and get an error! However when I declare the function as a variable first (below) it runs

###### Runs:

```
outerFunction (node *TreeNode, target int) bool {
  var checkSolution func(*TreeNode, int) bool
  checkSolutions = func(node *TreeNode, total int) bool {
        // ... DFS algo
        checkSolutions(node.Left)
        checkSolutions(node.Right)
    }
    
  return checkSolution(root, 0)
}
```

Is this the cleanest way to declare recursive inner functions in Go? For some reason it feels a little bit verbose to me so I just wanted to make this post to see if there's any Golang syntactic sugar intended for this situation that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

In a gist, this is the best you can get. There is nothing better here.

In the firat case, you can clearly see that the function `checkSolutions` is not decleared. Hence, when you use that inside the declaration, go compiler has no idea what that function is and what is it supposed to do (params and returns).

```
outerFunction (node *TreeNode, target int) bool {
  checkSolutions := func(node *TreeNode, total int) bool {
        // ... DFS algo
        checkSolutions(node.Left)    // Is not decleared yet to be used
        checkSolutions(node.Right)
    }
    
  return checkSolution(root, 0)
}
```

In other case, when you have defined what it is supposed to do, compiler can understand the definitions and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the snippet1, before assigning value all the statements to the right of `:=` has to be evaluated. Once the evaluation is complete it can be assigned memory.

In the snippet1, we are calling the function `checkSolution` before it exists. Therefore it throws error.

Whereas in the snippet2 `var checkSolution func(*TreeNode, int) bool` initializes and assigns memory. So it is in existence, which can be called by the inner function of `checkSolution`

I believe that this is the best way to achieve the recursion here.